# Caster type and placement for rotating cabinet

Tags: doors, cabinets, hinges, custom-cabinetry

I have a cabinet that I want to function as a sort of door to a storage space behind it. It will be fixed to the wall with a set of hinges, so that it can swing open. Because the cabinet with contents is rather heavy and I don't want to rely on the hinges alone to carry the weight, I want to put the cabinet on casters that will carry the load.

Since the cabinet is fixed to the wall with hinges, it will always turn at the same angle, in the same direction (and reverse), with the pivot point being the back corner where the hinges are attached. It seems like swivel casters are overkill for this: there's no steering or changing direction involved here.

However, if I use fixed casters, I'm wondering about the orientation. Do I just place the fixed casters parallel to the front edge? Do I put them at an angle, because they will always be making a turn? Are there calculations for optimal placement and angle here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the axle of the wheel intersect the axis of rotation of the door through the hinges.

Comment: So simple, why didn't I think of that? Thanks!